# Combobox based on another Combobox input SOMETIMES fails to correctly update

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I will try and explain this as concisely as possible as i am stumped. I have a spreadsheet containing a list of id numbers with a start and end date, and then another list of document numbers with a date.

I have created a combobox which allows the user to select one of the id numbers.

Based on the id number selected, the second combobox then allows the selection of a document number with a date that falls inbetween the start and end date of the selected idnumber.

I was able to achieve this using the filter function in excel. Once the id is selected form the initial combobox, the start and end date are populated which then feed into the filter function making the relevant documents appear.

The appearing documents in the filter function are then the source of the second combobox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g5G0.png)

Here is the code-
cbogrant is the id combobox
cbDocument is the document combobox

```
Private Sub cbogrant_Change()

EnableEvents = False

cbDocument.Value = ""
Labeluncert.Caption = ""
Labeldoc.Caption = ""
Labelpd.Caption = ""

EnableEvents = True

grnt = cbogrant.Value

Labelgrant.Caption = grnt


On Error Resume Next
vfrom = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(grnt, Sheets("SSDRPivot").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
tod = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(grnt, Sheets("SSDRPivot").Range("A:C"), 3, False)
bal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(grnt, Sheets("SSDRPivot").Range("A:F"), 6, False)

On Error GoTo 0
Label5.Caption = Format(bal, "#,##0.00")

Sheets("Data Validation").Range("K2") = vfrom
Sheets("Data Validation").Range("L2") = tod

dlrow = Sheets("Data Validation").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))


cbDocument.List = Sheets("Data Validation").Range("F2:H" & dlrow).Value

cbDocument.FontSize = 9


End Sub
```

This all works and 98 percent of the time the information is correct however at times randomly when switching ids back and forth i have noticed that the second combobox is showing incorrect information. My guess is that it is attempting to show the list too quickly not allowing enough time for the filter function to work.

Is there a way to ensure that all events have occured prior to the creation of the list? I have tried a one second delay to no avail.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` ?  If you *expect* to get matches in those 3 lines then ignoring any errors seems like a bad idea?

Comment: Very valid observation. You are correct that isnt necessary as the data is expected to be there. I had put it in the eventuality that some info was missing during the testing phase. Will make that correction.